# Trying to pass user uploaded image into tf.browser.fromPixels(), getting error that it is HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

> Error: Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number}, but was HTMLInputElement

Please excuse what I am sure is a simple fix, I am working on a college group project and have not worked with many of these tools before.

I am trying to classify a user uploaded image, but am getting this error once I get to tf.browser.fromPixels().

I assume I need to somehow convert it from HTMLInputElement to somthing else before calling tf.browser.fromPixels(), but am not sure how.

I will include the entire page below in case the error is being caused further up, or if you happen spot any errors I have not gotten to yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="cat, dog">
        <title>Intro to Software Development</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Logan Owens, Jacob Shaw, Brennen Denney, Euael Beyene">
        <meta name="description" content="Group Project">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload an Image</h1>
        <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <h2>Classification Result:</h2>
        <p id="result">Waiting for classification...</p>

        <script>
            const image_input = document.querySelector("#fileInput");
            const form = document.querySelector('form');
            const resultParagraph = document.getElementById('result');

            form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(form);
                
                try {
                    const response = await fetch('/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: formData
                        
                    });
                    const data = await detect(image_input)
                    consol.log(data)
                    resultParagraph.textContent = `Result:type="text/javascript" It's a ${data}`;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    resultParagraph.textContent = 'Error occurred while processing the image.';
                }
            })
                async function loadModel() {
                return tf.loadLayersModel('model.json')
            }
            function preprocess(imageData) {
                let imageTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageData);
                const pffset = tf.scalar(255.0);
                const normalized = tf.scaler(1.0).sub(resized.div(offset));
                const batched = normalized.expandDims(0);
                return batched;
            }
            async function detect(image){
                const model = await loadModel();
                const imageTensor = preprocess(image);
                const prediction = model.predict(imageTensor);
                if(prediction = "dogs"){
                    return "dog"
                }
                else if(prediction = "cats"){
                    return "cat"
                }
                else{ 
                    return "error"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you are passing the entire input element (HTMLInputElement) to the preprocess function instead of the actual image data.
const image_input = document.querySelector("#fileInput") is passed into detect and then pass into preprocess. Your need to pass the actual image data not the html element

Comment: Thank you, may I ask how I would get the image data instead of the input element?

Comment: you can use canvas